# Xcode SwiftUI PayPal Integration iOS

Tags: ios, swiftui, paypal

I am the founder of a Covid-19 relief nonprofit. I'm writing an app to accept donations and provide news and event information to anyone who has the app. I was wondering if there's any easy way to integrate a Paypal donation system into this? I thought BraintreeIOS would work but it seems to be outdated and doesn't support SwiftUI, only Swift.

Anyone have any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: PayPal has a way.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE What is it? I've done a lot of research and can't find anything besides Braintree IOS.

Comment: Well then, [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sdk-dev/native/) might come in handy

Comment: Be aware that Apple has specific requirements for collecting donations - https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#other-business-model-issues One of those is you must support ApplePay, so you will want to use Braintree or Square in addition to PayPal.  Note that you can always [UIViewRepresentable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewrepresentable) to present a UIKit view in SwiftUI.

Comment: You can also use the older SwiftUI lifecycle that presents your SwiftUI using a UIHostingViewController, then you have a root view controller that you can use to present the Braintree payment view controller.

Comment: @Paulw11 hey Paul, thank you very much for this info. Are there any other requirements besides Apple Pay's support in addition to PayPal? Also, does Braintree indeed include Apple Pay or is this a separate SDK altogether? Does Apple have integrated support with Apple Pay in swift? thanks again!

Comment: Follow the link in my previous comment to see the requirements for non-profit donations. Braintree includes ApplePay as an option on their UI, but if the user selects Apple Pay you need to present a PKPaymentButton and PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController yourself - This is described on the [github page](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-ios-drop-in)

Comment: You also need to be an [approved non-profit](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/nonprofits/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Native Checkout SDK might be overkill for donations. Most simply, open the following in a web browser or SafariViewController with an address bar:

> https://www.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_donations&item_name=STRING%20DESCRIBING%20PURPOSE%20OF%20DONATION&currency_code=USD&business=EMAIL_ADDRESS_OR_MERCHANT_ID

Use merchant ID from https://www.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/aboutBusiness , though primary email of PayPal account also works

You can even prefill the amount with `&amount=xxx%2exx` (though that gives no option for monthly recurrence)

For more see [HTML Variables for PayPal Payments Standard](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/), it's a legacy Web 2.0 integration but it gets the job done